# Python reflection, getter to methods

Tags: python, reflection, getattr, setattr

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10
    def print(self):
        print("hiiiiii")
```

For an object of A, we can easily access the attributes with `getattr` and `setattr`. Is there any way in Python to have an instance of class and a method name and call it indirectly, like:

```
MagicalMethod( A(), "print" )
```

then prints "hiiiiii" for me.

Comment: `getattr(A(), "print")()`? Methods are just callable attributes.

Comment: yup it means by passing an instance of class like A()  and the method name it calls the method for A()

Comment: however what you say doesn't work but throw no exception either

Comment: It *does* work.

Comment: yeah thanks, man, my bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

That would be `getattr`:

```
>>> getattr(A(), 'print')()
hiiiiii
```

(Note that you still have to *call* the return value of `getattr`; you can define a wrapper to do that for you:

```
def MagicalMethod(obj, name, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(obj, name)(*args, **kwargs)
```

)

`operator.methodcaller` provides a slightly different kind of indirection.

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> f = methodcaller('print')
>>> f(A())
hiiiiii
```

Comment: thank you so much, for the getattr I was not putting the brackets so it wasn't working, thank you again :)